# std::regex constructor throwing std::regex_error with what(): regex_error

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, gcc

I need to get some strings from a given line as below:

```
{"username":"wrongpass", "password":"abc", "email":"example@gmail.com"}
```

To be more specific, those in `""` are needed. Here is my code:

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex re(R"&(^{("(username|password|email)")\s*:\s*"(.*)"\s*,\s*("(username|password|email)")\s*:\s*"(.*)"\s*,\s*("(username|password|email)")\s*:\s*"(.*)"}$)&");
    return 0;
}
```

It is successfully compiled with `-std=c++11` using gcc version 8.1.0. But it throws an exception when running:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
```

I have no idea why it gives such an exception. I've searched online and found some similar problems, but they  were mainly due to using a compiler(gcc) that was too old to support regex.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that full regex support came very late to gcc, and that circa-2018 version of gcc may not have fully implemented it.

Comment: The input is JSON format and should be parsed using a [JSON parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+json+library). RegEx is not the right tool. You will loose so much time to get it working somehow and propably still miss edge case, e. g. how do you deal with escaped quotes and backslashes (`"password":"a\"b\\c"`)? Such characters are not uncommon in passwords.

Comment: The regex has special characters `{` and `}`, but expects them to be interpreted as matching characters.  Try `[{]` and `[}]` or escaping them.  (And I concur with zett42:  use a JSON parser to process JSON.  Regex is the wrong tool for the job.) [JSON Spirit](https://github.com/cierelabs/json_spirit) looks nice

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for your advice! It works now. I'm learning regex, and this is actually part of my homework of C++. JSON is mentioned as background in the description, but we are still required to use C++ regex library.